# Trying to Use PHP's Zip Archive - Extract To Doesn't Seem to be Working

Tags: php, zip, extract, php-ziparchive

Would appreciate some help on this. I've been trying to write a PHP script that Unzips a zip file that has been created using PHP's in-built Zip Archive extension.

The zipping-up process has been very straight forward but now I'm trying to unzip this to a particular folder and it doesn't seem to be working. The only thing it does is create the folder I've asked it to extract to. No files appear in that folder.

I've had no error messages.

Thanks in Advance. Here's my code:

```
<?php

  $root = str_replace('public_html', '', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
  $path = $root.'scripts.zip';

  $zip = new ZipArchive;
  $zipped = $zip->open($path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
  $folder = $root.'public_html/scripts/';

  if ($zipped) {

    $extract = $zip->extractTo($folder);

    if ($extract){

      echo 'Zip File Extracted';

    }

    $zip->close();  

  }

?>
```

Comment: Do you really want to use `ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE` flags to open an existing zip file?

Comment: Hi Mark, Unfortunately I have to.

Otherwise Zip Archive sees the file as an invalid zip file.

The fix for this is in the comments of this page - www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php

Comment: Because you're basically telling the open method to blast any file that already exists, and create a new empty zip file of that name... so of course it's doing exactly what you tell it to

Comment: So the real question should be why the original file won't open correctly when you don't use those flags: was it created correctly in the first place. What errors does it give? Have you tried checking using the ZipArchive class error codes?

Comment: I believe so, it was created using Zip Archive itself.

Edit: I've just downloaded the file and it won't open in WinRAR or in Windows' ZIP program.

Apologies, I assumed that Zip Archive would create a file that it could actually open itself.

Comment: Yes, the error code that's been coming out has been Error 19: ZIPARCHIVE::ER_NOZIP

Comment: Which means that it's not recognising your file as a zip file, suggesting that your original creation of the file hasn't created a valid file

Comment: Ok, I'll have to do some digging regarding the creation of the file itself then. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, just to keep you updated. I had a look at the creation of the file and that was absolutely fine. They problem lay in an FTP script when I was transferring the file to a different server. The FTP script used FTP_ASCII and was corrupting the file. I changed it to FTP_BINARY and this solved the issue.

Thanks again Mark :)

Comment: Achievement unlocked: case closed.... yet another happy customer

Answer (score 1):

I would modify your code to look like the one below.
What you were doing was creating a new zip file, not extracting the old one. `ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE` instructs the code to create a zip, `ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE` tells it to overwrite existing files in the zip.

So you are not extracting anything from the zip. This code below should work

```
 <?php
    $root = str_replace('public_html', '', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
    $path = $root.'scripts.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zipped = $zip->open($path); /*I have removed the ::CREATE & ::OVERWRITE methods*/
    $folder = $root.'public_html/scripts/';
    if ($zipped) {
       $extract = $zip->extractTo($folder);
       if ($extract){
           echo 'Zip File Extracted';
       }
       $zip->close();
    }
 ?>
```

Hope that helps